# How to display a variable's value in a message box?

Tags: java

I want to display the "number of names". Suppose if I enter two name, it should display ""you have entered 2 names.

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

```
public class MyName {
public static void main (String args [ ])

{
    int option;
    String userName;

    do
    {
        option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Want to enter another Name?");

    } while (option == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you have entered" + (number of names) + "names");

}
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @C.Lang when I posted that comment all the question said was "how to count number of loops?" and then there was code in the question description. :)

Comment: Thank you for reply. I am trying to figure that by myself. Actually, i Just joined the stackoverflow because i were not able to figure that by myself. My question is that I want to display the number of names in  showMessageDialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To count the iterations, you may do this :

```
int i=0; // create a counter
do {
    option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Want to enter another useraName?");
    i++; // increment the counter
} while (option == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you have entered " + i + " names"); // use it
```

But usually, you wouldn't have this problem as you should store the names :

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
do {
     ...
     names.add(enteredName);
while ...
```

After the loop, the number of names is `names.size()`.

Comment: Your counter is off by one.

Comment: Why is this made a community wiki?

Comment: @JBNizet The counter seems to correctly count the number of iterations, which seems to be the question (OP's code is missing the part where the name is entered).

Comment: I read the question as : the counter should count the number of times the user clicked the Yes button. The OP should confirm or infirm.

Comment: @JBNizet The question changed a few times. Initially it was "count the number of loops", which I translated as "count the number of iterations". In any case, I'd let OP adjust by one if necessary. As it's a CW answer, feel free to make it more clear if you think it would be better.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst The author checked the CW checkbox. Do you think it's a problem ?

Comment: Yes! that's what I am trying to figure out. The number of times the user clicked the Yes button. I want to display the number of count in ShowMessageDialog, as soon as the user hit "NO" option.

Comment: @user2178940: the message seems a bit odd though. You ask "Would you like to enter another name?" at least once implying that you've already recieved one name.

Comment: @C. Lang Yes. But I got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

By using a variable?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MyName {
public static void main (String args [ ])

{
    int option;
    String userName;

    int number = 0;
    do
    {
        number++;
        option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Want to enter another useraName?");

    } while (option == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you have entered" + (number of names) + "number");

}
}
```

Comment: your counter is off by one.